# SQL Query to get the count of a particular value in a column

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have used the below query to get a few columns. Now, this query is working fine and is giving the below output-

```
person_number         company               rule_id                 overtime_measure_hours              Reg_hours           Hour_type
10928                xyz                    y33t                            10                              10               Bereavement
10928                xyz                    y33t                            10                              10               Vacation
10928                xyz                    y33t                            10                              10               Paid Personal

3638                 abc                    y33t                            8                               8
```

i.e. I am getting all correct data for all the column. But if there is no data in hour_type column i am not getting any row just with reg_hours or overtime_measure_hours.
I want to tweak the below query such that I count the Regular element in the final output and if it is greater 2 then the above output comes and if
it is 1 then a single row without Hour_type comes like 4th row. Can i put where condition in count or is there any other way

```
SELECT person_number,
       company,
       rule_id,
       Sum(CASE
             WHEN elements = '1_5X' THEN measure
           END) AS overtime_measure_hours,
       Sum(CASE
             WHEN elements LIKE 'Regular%' THEN measure
           END) AS Reg_hours,
       hour     Hour_type
FROM   (SELECT person_number,
               company,
               rule_id,
               elements,
               papf.hour
        FROM   per_all_people_f papf,
               co_table co,
               rule_table RULE,
               time_track elements
        WHERE  elements.person_id = papf.person_id
               AND co.co_id = papf.co_id
               AND rule_table.rule_id = elements.rule_id)
UNION
SELECT person_number,
       company,
       rule_id,
       Sum(CASE
             WHEN elements = '1_5X' THEN measure
           END)      AS overtime_measure_hours,
       Sum(CASE
             WHEN elements LIKE 'Regular%' THEN measure
           END)      AS Reg_hours,
       absences_name Hour_type
FROM   (SELECT person_number,
               company,
               rule_id,
               elements,
               absences_name
        FROM   per_all_people_f papf,
               co_table co,
               rule_table RULE,
               time_track elements,
               absence_table ABSENCES_name
        WHERE  elements.person_id = papf.person_id
               AND co.co_id = papf.co_id
               AND rule_table.rule_id = elements.rule_id
               AND ABSENCES_name.person_id = papf.person_id)
```

Comment: In 1992 `JOIN` syntax was invented; after nearly ***three decades***, don't you think it's time to start using it?  Then you can start using `LEFT OUTER JOIN` instead of `(+)`, with the benefit that it's readable and it actually works *(`(+)` has cases where it doesn't work)*.

Comment: Please provide sample data and describe why current output is not what you want. Also please **minimize** your sample code, because all of the tables have no special influence on the result compared to single table with required columns.

Answer (score 0):

As @MatBailie told, use an "LEFT OUTER JOIN".
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp

→ Then you will get results even if "Hour Type" is NULL

I suppose you want something like this - I am actuell not sure in which table your column "Hour_type" is included:

```
SELECT
  person_number,
  company,
  rule_id,
  Sum(CASE WHEN elements = '1_5X' THEN measure END) AS vertime_measure_hours,
  Sum(CASE WHEN elements LIKE 'Regular%' THEN measure END) AS Reg_hours,
  hour Hour_type 
FROM
  co_table co,
  rule_table RULE,
  time_track elements,
  absence_table ABSENCES_name
  LEFT OUTER JOIN per_all_people_f papf ON elements.person_id = papf.person_id AND ABSENCES_name.person_id = papf.person_id)
WHERE
  co.co_id = papf.co_id
  AND rule_table.rule_id = elements.rule_id
```